# Collision detection is only affecting the last rendered object

Tags: javascript, jquery, collision-detection

I made a simple 2D game. Click the Start button, then click the gun to fire at moving targets which are generated with at random intervals with random classes, speeds and heights. For debugging purposes I've disabled most of the randomness. Collision detection has been added so that the ship colliding with the bullet turns red, the player scores a point and the bullet gets removed. This is all is working except for one problem: Only the last ship rendered is being detected as a collision. Any help would be appreciated. I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14181763/arraylist-only-detects-collision-of-last-added-object) and I'm not really sure it applies to my case.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1656361/test_game_v1-0/index.html
(hosted with Dropbox: demo won't work unless you allow scripts from dropbox to run in Chrome or Firefox-click the little shield icon)

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var score = 0;

  function getRandomInt (min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }

 // New Ship Creation // 

  function newShip (){
    var ship = 1; // var ship = Math.floor((Math.random()*3)+1);
    var shipPosition = Math.floor((Math.random()*150)+1);
    var speed = 0;
    var speedRandom = Math.floor((Math.random()*999)+1);
    if (ship == 1){
      ship = "slowShip";
      speed = 4001+speedRandom;
      } else if (ship == 2) {
      ship = "mediumShip";
      speed = 3001+speedRandom;
      } else if (ship == 3) {
      ship = "fastShip";
      speed = 2500+(speedRandom/2);
      }
    var div = "<div class='allShips " + ship + "'></div>";
    var shipClass = "."+ship;
    $('#gameFrame').prepend(div);
    $(shipClass).animate({left: 400}, speed, "linear", function(){
      $(this).remove();
    });  
    $('.allShips').first().css("top", shipPosition);
  }


  // Game Start //

  $("button.start").click(function(){
    var randomTime = getRandomInt(2000,2000); // (500,4500);

    setInterval(function() {
      newShip(); }, randomTime);

      // Gun Control //

      $('.gun').click(function() {
          $('.gun').after("<div class='bullet'></div>");
          $(".bullet").animate({top: '-10px'}, 1000,"linear", function(){
            $(this).remove();
          });
      });

      // Collision Detection //

      function collisions($div1, $div2) {
        var shipCount = $div1.length;
        var bulletCount = $div2.length;
        // console.log(shipCount);
        if (shipCount > 0 && bulletCount > 0) {
          var x1 = $div1.offset().left;
          var y1 = $div1.offset().top;
          var h1 = $div1.outerHeight(true);
          var w1 = $div1.outerWidth(true);
          var b1 = y1 + h1;
          var r1 = x1 + w1;
          var x2 = $div2.offset().left;
          var y2 = $div2.offset().top;
          var h2 = $div2.outerHeight(true);
          var w2 = $div2.outerWidth(true);
          var b2 = y2 + h2;
          var r2 = x2 + w2;

          if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2) {
            return false;
          } else {
          return true;
          }
        };  
      }

      // Collision Consequences //

      setInterval(function(){
        $('.allShips').each(function(){
          if(collisions($('.allShips'), $('.bullet'))){ 
            $(this).css("background-color", "red");
            score += 1;
            $('#score').text(score);
            $('.bullet').remove();  
          }  
        }); 
      }, 10);
  });   
});
```

Comment: At least try: `if(collisions($(this), $('.bullet'))){ ...`

Comment: Agree with Wolff, you are sending .allships each time in the loop, should just be the individual ship. Was gonna check it out, but couldn't get the demo to do anything

Comment: Was just able to test it in IE of all things. It's actually the last bullet that is being detected, not the last ship. Try firing 1 bullet at a time and you will see that you can hit multiple ships.

Comment: Could anyone explain why Wolff's solution of replacing `$(.allShips)` with `$(this)` solves my problem? I should have caught that mistake, but I wouldn't have thought that it would have fixed the problem.

Comment: Well, you were sending a jquery object with all ships and accessing properties from that object, which would only reference the first object in the collection. $(this) inside of your loop would refer to the individual ship at that iteration in the jquery collection

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your collision function:

```
function collisions($div1, $div2) {
    var shipCount = $div1.length;
    var bulletCount = $div2.length;
    // console.log(shipCount);
    if (shipCount > 0 && bulletCount > 0) {
      $div2.each(function(){
        var x1 = $div1.offset().left;
        var y1 = $div1.offset().top;
        var h1 = $div1.outerHeight(true);
        var w1 = $div1.outerWidth(true);
        var b1 = y1 + h1;
        var r1 = x1 + w1;
        var x2 = $(this).offset().left;
        var y2 = $(this).offset().top;
        var h2 = $(this).outerHeight(true);
        var w2 = $(this).outerWidth(true);
        var b2 = y2 + h2;
        var r2 = x2 + w2;

        if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2) {
          return false;
        } else {
        return true;
        }
     });
    };  
  }
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. However, I stupidly updated the code in the link to fix the problem. So, that might be the problem. And that's why you didn't see the 'last element' issue. Reverting the code now so that the link makes sense.